# How to measure relative light intensity (and ideally duration) of a xenon flashes, cheaply

Tags: flash, component-selection, light-sensor, instrumentation, arc

I want to compare the light intensity (and maybe also duration) of multiple xenon flash designs. It does not have to give me the readings in any real unit, as long as it is linear (or mathematicaly predictable), so I can calibrate it with a "standard candle".

The simplest method would be to stick a few sheets of paper over the flashes to reduce the intensity, and then use an LDR and a oscilloscope in a dark room. I am just worried that the response time of the LDR will be too slow for the very quick flash. I've considered photodiodes or phototransistors instead as they could possibly be faster, but I'm still not sure if they are the best option, or which one to get.

To make it more difficult, I don't want to spend more than £10 (not including any scope or power supply needed) on the circuit. I understand that I won't get great accuracy or precision for this price, but all I want to see is a trend, and I can vary the brightness difference between flashes to suit the precision of the sensor, in order to see the trend.

Comment: I think a photo-diode should work. Do you care about mimicking the frequency response of the human eye? If you are going to ultimately report lumens or lux then you need to do this. If so, you will need to invest in a filter, or buy a diode with included filter. Here is the first one I found: http://www.vishay.com/docs/81519/bpw21r.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LDR is far too slow . Xenon flashtubes put out very short pulses .A setup that I did a DCDC convertor for gave me 100 microsec light pulses .The photo transistor will work at a pinch ,photo diode would be better ,I actually used phototransistor and a transimpedence amplifier using two BC547 transistors .Hopefuly this is within your frugal budget.

Comment: There are some estimates of cellphone xenon flash durations and illuminance in the following article too, in case that helps the author spec out his measurement system, https://www.cap-xx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/CAP-XX_WP_0906_Comparison_of_xenon_flash_and_LED_flash_v3.pdf .